# How to identify statistical significance in a difference between means of grouped survey questions

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, likert

I'm looking at some survey data where the questions were on a Likert scale.  For each question I get what percentage respond positive/neutral/negative.  There are on the order of 30,000 survey respondents.

There are also some indices associated with the survey where a number of questions (usually 5) on a similar topic are grouped together, so you have the average positive/neutral/negative response rate for the grouping.

What is the appropriate test to identify statistically significant differences in these index values?  To be clear, two comparisons are being made:

1. the index of a subset (usually on the order of 1000 to 3000
   respondents) versus the rest of the population
2. the index of a subset of the population versus that same subset's index in a prior year's survey